# Flowbite Drawer doesn't work inside ngFor (Angular)

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using Flowbite (https://flowbite.com) which is a Tailwind CSS plugin as you know in my Angular project.

Everything is working perfectly except when I call a drawer button inside a table which is rendering with ngFor and I have no idea how to fix this.

It works perfectly when I put the drawer and the button outside of the ngFor

I intiated everything correctly it just doesn't work inside ngFor

app.component.ts:

```
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

ngOnInit(): void {
  initFlowbite();
}
```

this is my table code inside page.component.html

```
<table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
    <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">
      <tr>
        <th class="px-6 py-3">
            table header
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of this.data?.data;" class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-right">
          <!-- drawer init and toggle -->
          <div class="text-center">
            <button class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button" data-drawer-target="drawer-example" data-drawer-show="drawer-example" aria-controls="drawer-example">
            Show drawer
            </button>
          </div>
          <!-- drawer component -->
          <div id="drawer-example" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-white w-80 dark:bg-gray-800" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="drawer-label">
            <h5 id="drawer-label" class="inline-flex items-center mb-4 text-base font-semibold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
              <path d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5ZM9.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM12 15H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h1v-3H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v4h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z"/>
            </svg>Info</h5>
            <button type="button" data-drawer-hide="drawer-example" aria-controls="drawer-example" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 absolute top-2.5 right-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" >
                <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                  <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6"/>
                </svg>
                <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
            </button>
            <p class="mb-6 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Supercharge your hiring by taking advantage of our <a href="#" class="text-blue-600 underline dark:text-blue-500 hover:no-underline">limited-time sale</a> for Flowbite Docs + Job Board. Unlimited access to over 190K top-ranked candidates and the #1 design job board.</p>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                <a href="#" class="px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-900 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">Learn more</a>
                <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Get access <svg class="w-3.5 h-3.5 ml-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
              <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9"/>
            </svg></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because it is assigning the same value to the `id` attribute for every iteration to your `drawer-example` and `drawer-label`.

```
<div id="drawer-example" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-white w-80 dark:bg-gray-800" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="drawer-label">
  <h5 id="drawer-label" class="inline-flex items-center mb-4 text-base font-semibold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
```

Instead, you need to assign a unique value to id of each `drawer-example` and `drawer-label` and refer to that via attr.data-drawer-target and so on.

Here's your code rewritten with dynamic id and data attributes.

```
<table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
<thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-400">
    <tr>
        <th class="px-6 py-3">
            table header
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of this.data?.data; let i = index"
        class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700">
        <td class="px-6 py-4 text-right">
            <!-- drawer init and toggle -->
            <div class="text-center">
                <button
                    class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
                    type="button" [attr.data-drawer-target]="'drawer-example_' + i" [attr.data-drawer-show]="'drawer-example_' + i"
                    [attr.aria-controls]="'drawer-example_' + i">
                    Show drawer
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- drawer component -->
            <div [id]="'drawer-example_' + i"
                class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-white w-80 dark:bg-gray-800"
                tabindex="-1" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'drawer-label_' + i">
                <h5 [id]="'drawer-label_' + i"
                    class="inline-flex items-center mb-4 text-base font-semibold text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    <svg class="w-4 h-4 mr-2.5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <path
                            d="M10 .5a9.5 9.5 0 1 0 9.5 9.5A9.51 9.51 0 0 0 10 .5ZM9.5 4a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0 3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0-3ZM12 15H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h1v-3H8a1 1 0 0 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v4h1a1 1 0 0 1 0 2Z" />
                    </svg>Info</h5>
                <button type="button" [attr.data-drawer-hide]="'drawer-example_' + i" [attr.aria-controls]="'drawer-example_' + i"
                    class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 absolute top-2.5 right-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">
                    <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none"
                        viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                            d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6" />
                    </svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close menu</span>
                </button>
                <p class="mb-6 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Supercharge your hiring by taking advantage
                    of our <a href="#"
                        class="text-blue-600 underline dark:text-blue-500 hover:no-underline">limited-time sale</a>
                    for Flowbite Docs + Job Board. Unlimited access to over 190K top-ranked candidates and the #1
                    design job board.</p>
                <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                    <a href="#"
                        class="px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-gray-900 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">Learn
                        more</a>
                    <a href="#"
                        class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Get
                        access <svg class="w-3.5 h-3.5 ml-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
                            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                stroke-width="2" d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9" />
                        </svg></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because flowbite is initialized before the data is fetched.
you can introduce a delay before initializing flowbite.

```
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';

ngOnInit(): void {
setTimeout(() => {        
          initFlowbite();   
      }, 100);
}
```

or you can initialize flowbite only after getting data from function:

```
    getAllData(): void {
    //code to get data here

      setTimeout(() => {        
          initFlowbite();   
        }, 100);
      }
   }
```